# How to install pygame on visual studio 2017?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2017, pygame

I would like to be able to work on a small Pygame game in the Visual Studio 2017 IDE. I installed Python3.7 and the latest version of pygame with the installation pip, but I run the program, it can not find the module '' Pygame ''

Comment: Are you using any virtual environment?

Comment: What do you mean by virtual environment? If I am local?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

`pip install pygame`

Comment: already done, it's as if he would not be able to get the Pygame library in the C :, because my project is in the D:

Answer (score 0):

Open python idle and try to execute this code:

```py
import pygame

print (pygame.ver)
```

And print the result that you get, if you get that pygame module not found.
Verify that you have only python3 if you have two versions of python maybe you should use pip3 not pip for the installation,

> pip3 install pygame